# TypeError: Undefined is not an object - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm a beginner to development and I'm getting Undefined is not an object error. What am I doing wrong here? When I console log placeID it returns value, but selectedPlace returns undefined. Thanks.

```
const PlaceDetailScreen = props => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPlaces = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('https://tgr-admin.appspot.com/api/places')

      setPlaces(result.data)
    }

    getPlaces()
  }, [])

  const placeID = props.navigation.getParam('placeId')

  const selectedPlace = places.find(place => place._id === placeID)

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Image source={{ uri: selectedPlace.image }} style={styles.image} />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the **selectedPlace**, before **getPlaces** complete, the **places** is an empty array and **.find** method  returns **undefined**. Accessing an image prop on selectedPlace undefined throws an error. Perform null check before accessing the image prop on selectedPlace.

```
const PlaceDetailScreen = props => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPlaces = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('https://#')

      setPlaces(result.data)
    }

    getPlaces()
  }, [])

  const placeID = props.navigation.getParam('placeId')

  const selectedPlace = places.find(place => place._id === placeID)
  // selectedPlace is undefined and places equals []
  // perform null check before accessing image prop
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Image source={{ uri: selectedPlace && selectedPlace.image }} style={styles.image} />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, you're great. :) Also I'd like to ask 1 more question if you have time. When I use filter method instead of find, it returns an array. But when I console log selectedPlace.image it is undefined. What is the reason for that? Thank you very much again.

Comment: filter method return array of filtered objects, so access first array element then access image prop, like this ```selectedPlace[0] && selectedPlace[0].image```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aadil Mehraj's answer, wrapping the content with null check also works. So I can add more stuff inside.

```
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {selectedPlace && (
        <>
          <Image source={{ uri: selectedPlace.image }} style={styles.image} />

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MarkdownView styles={markdownStyles}>
              {selectedPlace.content}
            </MarkdownView>
          </View>

        </>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```